# Upload Dictionary in Solr for Spell Check

Tags: solr, lucidworks

I'm running into this problem this Solr: Solr can only spell check and give suggestions based on the files in the database. However, I want to add an English dictionary, so even if the word doesn't exist in the database, Solr can give suggestions based on the English dictionary.

I know I have to do this using a FileBasedSpellChecker in solrconfig.xml:

```
 <searchComponent name=”spellcheck” class=”solr.SpellCheckComponent”>
         <lst name=”spellchecker”>
             <str name=”classname”>solr.FileBasedSpellChecker</str>
             <str name=”name”>file</str>
             <str name=”sourceLocation”>spellings.txt</str>
             <str name=”characterEncoding”>UTF-8</str>
             <str name=”spellcheckIndexDir”>./spellcheckerFile</str>
         </lst>
     </searchComponent>
```

But I don't know how I can upload spellings.txt to Solr. I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":404,
    "QTime":1},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Specified dictionaries do not exist: file",
    "code":404}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to put your `spellings.txt` in the same folder where `solrconfig.xml` is. If I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Yeah that's what I guessed too. But the problem is I'm using Lucidworks Fusion, which builds on top of Solr and other things. Fusion doesn't expose where solrconfig is in their directories. I'm accessing it in the Fusion UI.